# How to select option from FLEX using Selenium with Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Python, when there is no Select -> options?

Here is image and part of the HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this drop down is not build up using `Select` and `options` tag from `selenium`.

So, we can not use `Select class` from selenium as well.

But we can try to directly click on `the drop down`, and then can `select` the `No` or `Yes` option.

by select mean above, is to click on them.

I would like you to try to `send the keys` directly.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@name, 'Are you a')]")))
ele.send_keys('YES')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately did not work... It doesn't want to send keys directly. Do you have any other suggestion?
I can find the element by xpath -> it works when I click on it (two options yes/no open). Then tried to use same xpath to send keys but does not work for me.

Comment: yes, the other approach would be to click on them, which is `1.` click on input box (which is drop down) and `2.` then click on either `yes ` or `no`. so we need three xpath for this case, do you happen to find all of them  ?

Comment: Here we have nightmare, when I click on field Yes and No options open. I can see also that new class opens. But when I want to copy xpath, immediately when I click something else these two options close :D
Input has type="hidden" and I think here is my problem

Comment: okay is that website url public ? if yes, the please share. if not , run this `print(driver.page_source)` and then share the entire HTML content, I will make replica of the same and would give you better solution.